# How to achieve this transition effect in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm very much new to d3 and was wondering how to achieve [this effect](http://i.imgur.com/VJbB9sj.gif), where multiple lines remain tangent to the perimeter of a circle at all times.

This is what I have thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/tz5KT/181/

```
function transition() {

svg.selectAll(".lines")
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        var tangent = findTangent(d.x, d.y);
        return tangent.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        var tangent = findTangent(d.x, d.y);
        return tangent.y;
    });

circleX = getRandom(0, width),
circleY = getRandom(0, height);

svg.select(".circle").transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("cx", circleX)
    .attr("cy", circleY)
    .each("end", transition);
}
```

I'm just not sure how to transition the lines from one position to the next, all while keeping them tangent to the circle. Any advice on how to do this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it

http://jsfiddle.net/tz5KT/219/

Check out my use of `attrTween`, it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the transition to the line points in the `transition` function, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tz5KT/177/
here it's a bit delayed tho

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you said, but the lines still aren't remaining tangent to the circle during the transition -- they're transitioning linearly from one point to the next: http://jsfiddle.net/tz5KT/181/

Comment: it's because the points are following a linear path from point A to B. To achieve the effect you want you would need to calculate the path as if it was doing a non linear path I think

Comment: That's right. Do you know how to calculate a non linear path?

Comment: you would need to know the slope of the trajectory, I think it should be this kind of trajectory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola but unfortunately I can't really help you on how to calculate that

Answer (score 0):

This is what you'll want in the transition function:

```
function transition() {

circleX = getRandom(0, width),
circleY = getRandom(0, height);

svg.select(".circle").transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("cx", circleX)
    .attr("cy", circleY)
    .each("end", transition);

    svg.selectAll(".lines")
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    var tangent = findTangent(d.x, d.y);
    return tangent.x;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    var tangent = findTangent(d.x, d.y);
    return tangent.y;
});

}
```

Comment: I tried what you said: http://jsfiddle.net/tz5KT/183/ but the lines still aren't tangent to the circle during the transition itself. Instead, they simply move from one coordinate to the next. Any ideas?

Comment: So the difference between your creation and the one you seek to replicate is that in yours, the connection between the line and the circle isn't concrete. It takes one of your initial line points and connects it to a random point on the circle every time. Each of your lines needs to get an initial connection to the circle and keep that connection rather than finding a new point on the circle every transition. Does this make sense? If point X is connected to the point at 46 deg on the circle, it needs to always stay connected to that point.

Comment: The line in my program isn't connecting to a random point on the circle: it's calculating the tangent point then connecting to that. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/zxqCw/69/ As for your recommendation, if point X is always connected to 46 deg on the circle, then the line won't be tangent to the circle.

Comment: Ok, so, after looking deeper, now that its transitioning correctly with the right timing, a simple white fill on the circle in the CSS gives you the effect you want. Try it out and let me know if thats exactly what you want.

Comment: I have actually realized that this isn't achieving the effect that you actually want. Im beginning to think that the data points in the effect you want are intelligently placed so that it wont break on transitions. That, or it is using a d3.force layout to keep the circle connected to the lines. Also, in the example you want to emulate, the circle is moving in a circular motion rather than all over the map which is keeping the lines connected. Anyway, that's as much as I will be able to figure out. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The example I wanted to emulate was actually written in a different programming language. I was just checking to see if it could be replicated easily with d3.